# Print json_encode object in Codeigniter View returned from controller

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I am trying to print the json_encode in my view. But its always displaying as json object. I want to print the below object in an html formatted output. I am just implementing a twitter like more button for the pagination results. Can some one help me.

**Here is my Controller:**

```
function get_results($offset)
    {
    $this->load->model('my_model');
    $this->data['latest_messages'] = $this->my_model->searchresult($offset);
    $this->output->set_header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    echo '<script> var data = ' . json_encode($this->data['latest_messages']). ' </script>';

    }
```

**Here is my View:**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
google.load("jquery", "1.10.1");
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var num_messages = <?=$num_messages?>;
    var loaded_messages = 0;
    $("#more_button").click(function(){
    loaded_messages += 10;
    $.get("<?php echo $base_url;?>" + "controller/get_results/" + loaded_messages,            function(data){
                $("#main_content").append(data);

            });

            if(loaded_messages >= num_messages - 10)
            {
                $("#more_button").hide();
            }
        })
    })
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=base_url();?>css/main.css" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
   <?php $this->load->view('includes/topbar'); ?>
    <?php $this->load->view('includes/menu'); ?>      
    <?php $this->load->view('includes/left'); ?>        

  <div id="contentwrap">
    <div id="content">

        <div id="main_content">
                <?php
                foreach($this->data['latest_messages'] as $message)
                {
                    echo $message->email . ' - ' . '<br />';
                }
                ?>
        </div>
    <div id="more_button">
        More
    </div>
  </div>     
  </div>
    <?php $this->load->view('includes/right'); ?>   
    <?php $this->load->view('includes/foot'); ?>
```

When I click on More link, the results are loading fine but I want to display the results in a nice formatted output instead of json object as shown below

```
[
{" id":"11"," group_fk":"1"," email":"test1@gmail.com"," username":"test1"},
{" id":"12"," group_fk":"1"," email":"test2@gmail.com"," username":"test2"},
{" id":"13"," group_fk":"1"," email":"test3@gmail.com"," username":"test3",},
]
```

Comment: `json_encode` works best when transferring php arrays/variables into a `javascript array/variable`.  Since you are using `echo` for the `json_encode` results, it is being outputted on the page.  So, perhaps you should echo it into a javascript array and than use that for the outputting of the objects?

Comment: Here is your code:  `echo json_encode($this->data['latest_messages']);`, this is why it is showing as it does.  You need to assign it to a js variable instead.  like:  `echo '<script> var oVal = ' . json_encode($this->data['latest_messages']) . '; </script>`  And than use `oVal.id`, `oVal.group_fk`, `oVal.email`, and `oVal.username` to output it via javascript where needed.

Comment: So Do I need to remove the `echo` for `json_encode`?

Comment: You should echo it within a script tag and put it within a js variable as I showed...  And than use it that way if you even really need to use `json_encode` at all.

Comment: I have updated the controller as per your comment. Now the more button never works :-(. Sorry I am kind of new to codeigniter and jquery

Comment: Do you have a link to point me to so I can see it?

Comment: This is what I am following: http://www.thetutorialblog.com/php/twitter-like-pagination-using-codeigniter-and-jquery/

Comment: why did you need to parse the array if you compiled it to json and append it to the `#main_content` ?

Comment: just call the json objects as @Solomon Closson said

Comment: I want to display the data in a nice formatted way. I have done the way Solomon suggested but now the data is not appending to `#main_content`

Comment: The MIME type shouldn't be `application/json` if you are sending `<script> ...` that is HTML my friend.

Comment: Hey Alex, Eventhough I changed it to html, it doesn't make sense in my output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so you're getting results in json format. You just need to manipulate those results in your ajax return handler and then append them to the div:

```
$.get("<?php echo $base_url;?>" + "controller/get_results/" + loaded_messages,  
    function(data){
        var data = JSON.parse(data);
        var output = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
            output += data[i].email + ' - <br />';
        }
        $("#main_content").append(output);
    }
);
```

Comment: Hey swatkins. thank you for your answer. When I click on More button. it is appending data as `undefined - 
undefined - 
undefined - 
undefined -`

Comment: can you add a `console.dir(data);` under the `function(data){` line and tell me what the output is?

Comment: No change in output. Its the same `undefined`

Comment: What does the console say?

Comment: Hey swatkins, I have updated the console output within your answer. Thank you for supporting.

Comment: Hey swatkins, your code works after adding `var data = JSON.parse(data);` Thank you for providing the solution